# Firebird query pivot

Tags: pivot, firebird

I have a Firebird sql query that returns 3 fields: `Surname`, `Name` and `date` as (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)

```
select Surname, Name, "WHEN" from users
left join attendant on (users.id = attendant.userid);
```

This is the result:

```
Surname Name    2018-04-11 08:35:37
Surname Name    2018-04-11 12:52:30
Surname Name    2018-04-11 13:44:18
Surname Name    2018-04-11 17:08:05
Surname Name    2018-04-12 08:31:17
Surname Name    2018-04-12 12:36:07
Surname Name    2018-04-12 13:28:30
Surname Name    2018-04-12 17:44:55
```

What I want to achieve is to put the date field of the same day (YYYY-MM-DD) in the same row.

```
Surname Name    2018-04-11 08:35:37 2018-04-11 12:52:30 2018-04-11 13:44:18 2018-04-11 17:08:05
Surname Name    2018-04-12 08:31:17 2018-04-12 12:36:07 2018-04-12 13:28:30 2018-04-12 17:44:55
```

Is this possible with Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

A pivot transposes rows to columns based on a discriminator column. Your example data doesn't show a discriminator column, and the data also seems to indicate that this could lead to a variable number of columns (depending on the attendance per date), which is not possible in Firebird. Instead it looks like you want to aggregate those dates in a single column.

Assuming that is what you want, you can use [`LIST`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-list) combined by a group by on the date part of the timestamp, for example:

```
select surname, name, list("WHEN", ' ')
from users
left join attendant on users.id = attendant.userid
group by surname, name, cast("WHEN" as date)
```

Be aware: `LIST` does not guarantee an order. You may need to use an intermediate `order by` on `"WHEN"` in a sub-query as a work around, but that trick does not always work (especially as in this case we're grouping on a derivative of `"WHEN"`).